# What is the proper procedure when trying to test your database in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I'm pretty new to databases and I have this assignment that I've completed where I had to look at a merged Entity Relationship Diagram and then create Drop Tables, Tables (with constraints and identity's), Alterations and Indexes. I'm pretty sure I've coded everything correctly but the only area I'm a little unsure about, it's how to test that the database will actually function when executing it. My instructor gave me a TestData.sql file that I just have to refer to the database and then execute and it should insert all the data into the tables and drop everything correctly. I have it all hooked up properly on SQL Server Management Studio but I forget what steps I should be taking in order to test the proper execution of the tables. I'll post some of my code so you guys can take a look. Any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Also, when it says in the Test Data SQL code "IMPORTANT! If you need to run this script more than once you must drop and recreate your tables first to reset the identity properties." --Does this mean that if I run into any errors while trying to execute the test data, I will have to execute the DROP TABLES first and then maybe copy and paste all the TABLES back into the Database file? I don't actually have to manually type all the TABLES again, just need to re-enter them as "new" so the system will kind of reset it's identity properties?

If you guys need me to post more of the code for clarification, just let me know. Thanks for taking the time to read this :)

**Update:** I'm getting 2 error messages when trying to execute the TestData script: "Invalid object name 'SaleDetail'." and "Invalid object name 'Author'." I've also provided the rest of the code from my Database script file for you to take a look at. I'm almost certain everything is correct.

Database Tables Code (this is the complete code script)

```
USE Lab2A_BooksGalore
 GO

 /*------ Drop Table Statements ------*/

 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SaleDetail')
    DROP TABLE SaleDetail
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'AuthorTitle')
    DROP TABLE AuthorTitle
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Title')
    DROP TABLE Title
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Publisher')
    DROP TABLE Publisher
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Category')
    DROP TABLE Category
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Author')
    DROP TABLE Author
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Sale')
    DROP TABLE Sale
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Employee')
    DROP TABLE Employee
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customer')
    DROP TABLE Customer

 /*------- Create Table Statements -------*/

 CREATE TABLE Customer
 (
    CustomerNumber      int
        CONSTRAINT PK_Customer_CustomerNumber
            PRIMARY KEY
        IDENTITY (1, 1)                     NOT NULL,
    LastName            varchar(30)         NOT NULL,
    FirstName           varchar(30)         NOT NULL,
    [Address]           varchar(40)         NULL,
    City                varchar(30)         NULL,
    Province            char(2)
        CONSTRAINT DF_Customer_Province
            DEFAULT ('AB')                  NULL,
    PostalCode          char(6)
        CONSTRAINT CK_Customer_PostalCode
            CHECK (PostalCode LIKE '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]')
                                            NULL,
    HomePhone           char(10)
 )

 CREATE TABLE Employee
 (
    EmployeeNumber      int
        CONSTRAINT PK_Employee_EmployeeNumber
            PRIMARY KEY
        IDENTITY (300, 1)                   NOT NULL,
    [SIN]               char(9)             NOT NULL,
    LastName            varchar(30)         NOT NULL,
    FirstName           varchar(30)         NOT NULL,
    [Address]           varchar(40)         NULL,
    City                varchar(20)         NULL,
    Province            char(2)
        CONSTRAINT DF_Employee_Province
            DEFAULT ('AB')                  NULL,
    PostalCode          char(6)
        CONSTRAINT CK_Employee_PostalCode
            CHECK (PostalCode LIKE '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]')
                                            NULL,
    HomePhone           char(10)            NULL,
    WorkPhone           char(10)            NULL,
    Email               varchar(40)         NULL,
 )

 CREATE TABLE Sale
 (
    SaleNumber          int
        CONSTRAINT PK_Sale_SaleNumber
            PRIMARY KEY
        IDENTITY (3000, 1)                  NOT NULL,
    SaleDate            datetime            NOT NULL,
    CustomerNumber      int
        CONSTRAINT FK_Sale_CustomerNumber_Customer_CustomerNumber
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(CustomerNumber)
                                            NOT NULL,
    EmployeeNumber      int
        CONSTRAINT FK_Sale_EmployeeNumber_Employee_EmployeeNumber
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeNumber)
                                            NOT NULL,
    Subtotal            money
        CONSTRAINT CK_Sale_Subtotal
            CHECK (Subtotal <= Total)       NOT NULL,
    GST                 money               NOT NULL,
    Total               money
        CONSTRAINT CK_Sale_Total
            CHECK (Total >= Subtotal)       NOT NULL,
 )

 CREATE TABLE Author
 (
    AuthorCode          int
        CONSTRAINT PK_Author_AuthorCode
            PRIMARY KEY
        IDENTITY (100, 1)                   NOT NULL,
    LastName            varchar(30)         NOT NULL,
    FirstName           varchar(30)         NOT NULL,
 )

 CREATE TABLE Category
 (
    CategoryCode        int
        CONSTRAINT PK_Category_CategoryCode
            PRIMARY KEY
        IDENTITY (1, 1)                     NOT NULL,
    [Description]       varchar(40)         NOT NULL,
 )

 CREATE TABLE Publisher
 (
    PublisherCode       int
        CONSTRAINT PK_Publisher_PublisherCode
            PRIMARY KEY
        IDENTITY (200, 1)                   NOT NULL,
    [Name]              varchar(40)         NOT NULL,
 )

 CREATE TABLE Title
 (
    ISBN                char(10)
        CONSTRAINT PK_Title_ISBN
            PRIMARY KEY                     NOT NULL,
    Title               varchar(40)         NOT NULL,
    SuggestedPrice      smallmoney
        CONSTRAINT DF_Title_SuggestedPrice
            DEFAULT (0)                     NOT NULL,
    NumberInStock       smallint
        CONSTRAINT CK_Title_NumberInStock
            CHECK (NumberInStock >= 0)      
        CONSTRAINT DF_Title_NumberInStock
            DEFAULT (0)                     NOT NULL,
    PublisherCode       int
        CONSTRAINT FK_Title_PublisherCode_Publisher_PublisherCode
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Publisher(PublisherCode)
                                            NOT NULL,
    CategoryCode        int
        CONSTRAINT FK_Title_CategoryCode_Category_CategoryCode
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Category(CategoryCode)
                                            NOT NULL,
 )

 CREATE TABLE AuthorTitle
 (
    ISBN                char(10)
        CONSTRAINT FK_AuthorTitle_ISBN_Title_ISBN
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Title(ISBN)
                                            NOT NULL,
    AuthorCode          int
        CONSTRAINT FK_AuthorTitle_AuthorCode_Author_AuthorCode
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Author(AuthorCode)
                                            NOT NULL,
 )

 CREATE TABLE SaleDetail
 (
    SaleNumber          int
        CONSTRAINT FK_SaleDetail_SaleNumber_Sale_SaleNumber
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Sale(SaleNumber)
                                            NOT NULL,
    ISBN                char(10)
        CONSTRAINT FK_SaleDetail_ISBN_Title_ISBN
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Title(ISBN)
                                            NOT NULL,
    SellingPrice        money               NOT NULL,
    Quantity            int                 NOT NULL,
    Amount              money               NOT NULL,
 )

 /*----------------- Alter Table Statements --------------------*/
 ---1) Add a char(10) attribute named WorkPhone to the Customer Table
 ALTER TABLE Customer
    ADD WorkPhone char(10) NULL
 GO
 ---2) Add a varchar(30) attribute named Email to the Customer Table
 ALTER TABLE Customer
    ADD Email varchar(30) NULL
 GO
 ---3) Add a constraint to make sure the correct format is followed for the Email attribute
 ALTER TABLE Customer
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Customer_Email
    CHECK (Email LIKE '[a-z, 0-9][a-z, 0-9][a-z, 0-9]%@[a-z, 0-9][a-z, 0-9][a-z, 0-9]%.[a-z, 0-9][a-z, 0-9]%')
    --- Match For:         b         8         l      @    g         v         t      .    c         a
 GO
 ---4) Add a char(1) attribute named Active that's required for the Employee Table
 ALTER TABLE Employee
    ADD Active char(1) NOT NULL
 GO
 ---5) Add a constraint to make sure the default character is used for the Active attribute
 ALTER TABLE Employee
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Employee_Active
    DEFAULT ('y')
 GO

 /*------------------ Foreign Key Index Statements -----------------*/
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Sale_CustomerNumber
    ON Sale (CustomerNumber)

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Sale_EmployeeNumber
    ON Sale (EmployeeNumber)

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Title_PublisherCode
    ON Title (PublisherCode)

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Title_CategoryCody
    ON Title (CategoryCode)

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_AuthorTitle_ISBN
    ON AuthorTitle (ISBN)

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_AuthorTitle_AuthorCode
    ON AuthorTitle (AuthorCode)

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SaleDetail_SaleNumber
    ON SaleDetail (SaleNumber)

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SaleDetail_ISBN
    ON SaleDetail (ISBN)

 GO
```

Test Data Code(this is only a snippet being this script is 100% accurate - provided by instructor)

```
USE Lab2A_BooksGalore
GO

--Lab 2 insert script
--IMPORTANT! If you need to run this script more than once you must drop and recreate your tables first to reset the identity properties.

--Delete existing data in the tables, if there is any
Delete From SaleDetail
Delete From Sale
Delete From AuthorTitle
Delete From Title
Delete From Employee
Delete From Customer
Delete From Category
Delete From Publisher
Delete From Author
Go

Insert into Author
    (LastName, FirstName)
Values
    ('Smith', 'Sammy'),
    ('Greens', 'George'),
    ('Jones', 'Johnny'),
    ('Davidson', 'David'),
    ('Robertson', 'Rob'),
    ('Abbots', 'Abe'),
    ('Bakers', 'Bob'),
    ('Caters', 'Clem'),
    ('Semenko', 'Dave'),
    ('Franky', 'Fran'),
    ('Horton', 'Harry'),
    ('Kelly', 'Kevin'),
    ('Lambert', 'Larry'),
    ('Johnson', 'Jon'),
    ('Anderson', 'Ander'),
    ('Peterson', 'Peter'),
    ('Jensen', 'Jens'),
    ('Issacsen', 'Issac')

Insert into Publisher
    (Name)
Values
    ('Addison Westley'),
    ('SAMS'),
    ('Harlequin'),
    ('Self Publish Inc'),
    ('Microsoft Press'),
    ('Jones and Bartlett'),
    ('WROX'),
    ('West'),
    ('Premier')


Insert into Category
    (Description)
Values
    ('Computers'),
    ('Business'),
    ('Human Relation'),
    ('Electronics'),
    ('Designs'),
    ('Miscellaneous'),
    ('Media Design'),
    ('Information Technologies')
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here? What is it that you need help with?

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I wasn't sure how to ask this question. After making a database, you need to make sure that the data will actually fill the tables right? I have the 2 separate files - one's the database and the other is the test data. I'm just asking how you go about making sure that your database is working like it should. I believe I've referenced the database to the test data properly, but I'm wondering which areas I'm going to have to highlight first and execute in order to test the database. I just need to make sure that the database is actually filling the tables and dropping them

Comment: I would just move all of this together. And remove the delete statements. Then it will just always build new tables. These tables are tiny so a dozen inserts is going to take milliseconds.

Comment: Ok, it's just because my instructor wants us to use this test data script the way it is. It's going to delete any old data and insert the new data. I've executed it a couple times and it's giving me a couple error messages that I don't quite understand. I'm going to update my post with the rest of the code and include the error messages. Any guidance would be great!

Comment: Looking at this question, I realize it's way too vague and pretty stupid. I apologize. I'm going to try and break this down and will re-post if needed. Thanks anyway!